# Debugging the multithreaded application

Tags: multithreading

I have application in Linux with 5 threads.

```
Thread1..Thread5
```

I have a critical section which is buffer holding some data.

I have apply the mutex lock and unlock functions for this critical section

```
lock()

bufferdata

unlock
```

All the threads are accessing the data in the synchronized manner.

Now for example

`thread 3` acquired the lock and processed the buffer data. In processing the buffer it has overwritten some data which made the buffer overflowed

After corrupting data the thread 3 unlocked the critical section.

Now when the `thread 5` acquired the lock and tried to do some operations on the corrupted memory and due to this the whole process got core dumped.

In general if we attach the core to GDB and do a back trace it will show you the call stacks for all the threads in a process.

Is there anyway in linux systems to find the culprit thread (here `thread 3`). If so please do let me know the process to find the culprit thread

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For buffer overflows and other types of memory corruption, [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is probably the right tool. There is no "one right way" to debug, and debugging multi-threaded programs is particularly hard. There's no substitute for experience.

I should also add that unit tests, assertions, and good code documentation help immensely.